# Multiple RewriteRule in htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am beginner in PHP and Apache. I am trying to use URL Rewriting for my website, which can have following URIs.

```
1. http://localhost:8080/home
2. http://localhost:8080/dell
```

For the first URI, there is **home.php** file available and I edited .htaccess file with following rewrite rule.

```
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC]
```

Second URI is dynamic - means there is no **dell.php** available for it that could handle the request. So I wrote following RewriteCond.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ list.php?page=$1
```

So as a whole, my .htaccess file is

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC] [N]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ list.php?page=$1
```

So when I request *localhost:8080/home*, home.php is duly responded but when I request *localhost:8080/dell*, an error is responded

> "The requested URL /dell.php was not found on this server."

I think only first RewriteRule takes precedence and second one is not even read by Apache server. Changing order does not work either. My question here is what RewriteRule(s) should I use that could work in both case - PHP file exists & does not exist?

Thank you for your opinion and guidance.

Ritesh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do a pre-emptive check against the `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}` with a .php after it to see if that exists *before* you try to rewrite it, otherwise URI's like **dell** will get blindly rewritten:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: Thank you. It works. Could you please explain how does [L] works?

Comment: @Ritesh It means to end the rewriting for the current loop. Since you've rewritten to an existing php file, the next rule would never get applied anyways, so there's no point in having the `[N]` flag. And you're not doing any case matching in your regex so no need to `[NC]` either.